# Remove duplicates from List of class objects, based on string array instance property

Tags: c#, linq

```
class RowData
{
    string Name;
    string[] Aliases;
}

List<RowData> rowData = new List<RowData>();
rowData.Add(new RowData { Name = "John Doe", Aliases = new string[] { "johndoe", "jdoe" } });
rowData.Add(new RowData { Name = "Jane Doe", Aliases = new string[] { "janedoe", "jdoe" } });
rowData.Add(new RowData { Name = "John Doe", Aliases = new string[] { "johndoe", "jdoe" } });

List<string[]> aliasList;

foreach(var row in in rowData)
{
    if(aliasList.Any(obj => obj.SequenceEqual(row.Aliases)))
    {
        continue;
    }
    aliasList.Add(row.Aliases);

    MakeRow(row.Name, row.Aliases);
}
```

Final result should only contain item at index 0 & 1 of List, as Aliases of items at index 0 & 2 are equal

I’ve tried different ways of filtering out rows where Aliases are common from the list of objects of type RowData, but this is the best way I was able to do this. Is there any better way of doing this using LINQ?

Comment: Show an example what you want to get as result because is unclear for me.

Comment: Why you use `SequenceEqual` at all? I think it doesn't matter in which order the aliases are, does it?

Comment: @TimSchmelter It’s to check whether the row with exact same items have been added before. Obviously it can be modified to make the order irrelevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a custom `IEqualityComparer<RowData>` which you can use for many LINQ methods. In this case you can use it for `Distinct`:

```
public class RowDataAliasComparer : IEqualityComparer<RowData>
{
    public bool Equals(RowData x, RowData y)
    {
        if (x?.Aliases == null && y?.Aliases == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (x?.Aliases == null || y?.Aliases == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return x.Aliases.OrderBy(a => a).SequenceEqual(y.Aliases.OrderBy(a => a));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(RowData obj)
    {
        if (obj?.Aliases?.Any() != true)
        {
            return int.MinValue;
        }

        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 0;
            foreach (string alias in obj.Aliases.OrderBy(a => a))
                hash ^= (alias?.GetHashCode() ?? 0);
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

So the code to remove the duplicates is easy:

```
rowData = rowData.Distinct(new RowDataAliasComparer()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `DistinctBy()` that might be a bit cleaner. This is order-sensitive implementation. It's easy to make it insensitive by using `OrderBy()`

```
public class StringArrayComparer : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<string>>
{
    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<string>? x, IEnumerable<string>? y)
        => Enumerable.SequenceEqual(x, y);

    public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<string> obj)
    {
        // copy of GetHashCode() method of Tim Schmelter's answer
        if (obj.Any() != true)
        {
            return int.MinValue;
        }

        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 0;
            foreach (string alias in obj)
                hash ^= (alias?.GetHashCode() ?? 0);
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

and usage

```
var filteredRows = rowData.DistinctBy(s => s.Aliases, new StringArrayComparer());
```

Comment: Your `GetHashCode` implementation ignores the order whereas the `Equals` takes it into account(`SequenceEqual`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq and string.Join

```
var _result= rowData.GroupBy(d => 
          new { d.Name, v = string.Join("|", d.Aliases) 
              }).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
List<RowData> rowData = new List<RowData>();
rowData.Add(new RowData { Name = "John Doe", Aliases = new string[] { "johndoe", "jdoe" } });
rowData.Add(new RowData { Name = "Jane Doe", Aliases = new string[] { "janedoe", "jdoe" } });
rowData.Add(new RowData { Name = "John Doe", Aliases = new string[] { "johndoe", "jdoe" } });

List<RowData> distinctData = rowData
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Aliases })
    .Select(group => group.First())
    .ToList();
```